# Why is Big-Oh notation useful when it's so easy to find a technically correct Big-Oh of most algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, big-o

My understanding is that if an algorithm is `O(1)` it is also `O(n)`, `O(n^2)`, `O(n^3)` and so on which makes it seem useless.  For example, if someone asked me for the Big-Oh notation of any algorithm, I could just say `O(n^n)` without thinking about it (literally) and be technically correct most of the time.

Since (it's my understanding that) this is true, how is this useful information?  To use an analogy, if I asked someone how many houses they own, an answer like, "1 to infinity" isn't very informative.  A useful answer (this is kind of like Big-Theta) would be "1".

Comment: Big-O is exactly as useful as the phrase "at most".  This phrase clearly *can* be useless: "I own at most a bazillion houses".  Does that make the phrase itself useless?

Comment: @j_random_hacker no it does not, and good explanation I might add.  But when you ask someone to quantify something, they don't *usually* answer with the phrase "at most".  Usually they say, "about" or "around".  But in computer science we seem to *usually* say, "at most".  And it seems when computer scientists know "about" or "around" they answer with "at most" instead.  That's the confusing thing to me.

Comment: I like John Kugelman's comment -- basically Big-O just got popular :) I guess enough programmers got the gist of it, and usually the most interesting upper bound to talk about is the lowest one, so that's the meaning that "*the* Big-O of XYZ" acquired.  Also (as he says) although Big-Theta is much more informative, it's usually much harder to get. As to why we have Big-Anything-At-All, it's because we want to measure time or space in a way that doesn't depend on the particular instruction set your computer uses.

Answer (score 8):

Big-O establishes **an** upper bound. If you know that an algorithm is O(n<sup>2</sup>) then you know its complexity is *at worst* quadratic. It could in fact be O(n) or O(1) but it's definitely not O(n<sup>3</sup>). It's very useful to figure out upper bounds on runtime for algorithms.

You are correct that the question, "What's the Big-O of this algorithm?" is poorly worded. The word "the" is incorrect. There's no one Big-O of an algorithm. There are many. Infinitely many. Big-O does not establish a **tight** upper bound. That's where Big-Theta comes in. Big-Theta asserts both an upper and lower bound: it gives an exact asymptotic bound. The question should be, "What's the Big-Theta of this algorithm?"

But it's important not to throw Big-O out, because not all algorithms have exact bounds known. [Matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication) is a well known problem that doesn't have an established Big-Theta. The naive algorithm is O(n<sup>3</sup>) and the state-of-the-art is O(n<sup>2.3727</sup>). That's **an** upper bound but it's probably not **the** (optimal) upper bound. Big-Theta lies somewhere between O(n<sup>2.3727</sup>) and Ω(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: Why don't they create a new Greek letter notation that represents "the lowest known upper bound"?  That way I couldn't "cheat" the way I did in my question.

Comment: Usually the right question is "What's the Big-Theta of XYZ?" rather than "What's the Big-O?" But the pasty, sickly Big-Theta isn't as popular as Mr. Captain of the Football Team "Big-O".

Comment: @tieTYT: I'm guessing because the lowest known upper bound can change over time as better algorithms (or better analyses of existing algorithms) are discovered. Mathematical notation is most useful if it always means the same thing, regardless of what time you read it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [letter by Donald Knuth](http://micromath.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/donald-knuth-calculus-via-o-notation/) for proposing the O notation to American Mathematical Society

Answer (score 0):

Saying any algorithm is O(n^n) is not correct, because big-Oh refers to a tight upper bound. We also do not say an algorithm is O(n^n), but rather the algorithm's time complexity is in O(n^n).

I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Can you show me a credible reference that says that big-Oh is a tight upper bound?

Comment: Big-Oh is an asymptotically upper bound by the formal definition; i.e., 0 <= f(n) <= cg(n) => f(n) in O(g(n)) for some constant c. I suppose you are correct this could render a loose upper bound, however in practice big-Oh always refers to tight upper bound. Otherwise the notation would be of little use (which is not the case.)